# Novel that had a plant based character waking up in the first few chapters

Tags: story-identification, novel

About 8-10 years ago I read the first few chapters of a novel I obtained from a fantasy writer's website. I think it was the author’s first published novel.

The main character was a girl who saw her family killed. She escaped with her brother, but interspersed with this was a plant-based character waking up after many years of slumber.

Unfortunately, I could not read any more as that was the limit of the sample and I did not see anything about it after.

Comment: Makes me think of Sheri Tepper's [_The Family Tree_](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/64701.The_Family_Tree?from_search=true), but I don't think that really matches.

Comment: English, right? Got any names or other details? ... How would you have found the site?

Comment: The website will have been one for writers and was in English.... I want to say Fantasy Writers of America or something like that... The guy put up a sample for people to read but the book was definitely getting published....